# Is Form_Load in Access 2007 generic?

Tags: ms-access-2007

Having a basic problem with Form_Load.  I have some code for that procedure.  I have it generated for a particular form, but it seems to open on the other form I have in the app as well.  Is there just one Form_load procedure that gets executed for all forms or did I miss something?  If not, then I understand somehow I will have to put code to only do certain things for certain forms.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is a Form_Load event handling method for each Form.

You have very likely wired up the same Procedure to 2 forms.

[Please show code for a more definitive answer.]

Comment: Thanks - this addressed my question.